# Class calling member function through Eval()

Tags: php, eval

Yes, I am quite aware of how horrible Eval() is, I have no choice, it is for an assignment and the professor has instructed us to use it.

I am having trouble figuring out why PHP won't let me call a class's member function from within the class when using Eval().  For example:

```
$code="class evalTest{
    function f1(){
        echo 'f1';
        f2();
    }
    function f2(){
        echo 'f2';
    }
}

$x=new evalTest();
$x->f2();
$x->f1();";

eval($code);
echo 'test';
```

The above code will print out:

```
f2f1
```

and the rest of the page will be blank.  It seems like the entire PHP script stops as soon as I call a function from within a function through Eval().  Even the final "echo 'test';" is not printed.

Is there some trick to getting this to work, or is this a limitation of Eval()?  Again, I would avoid using Eval() if I could, but we were specifically instructed to use it.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL)` will tell you exactly why. With that said, every time you use `eval`, an African child will die of starvation.

Comment: Why the downvote? Anything wrong with this question??

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to call `$this->f2();` instead of `f2()`.

You also need to escape `$` if you are using double quotes, because any `$blah` in double-quote strings are interpreted as **variable references**.

```
<?php
$code="class evalTest{
    function f1(){
        echo 'f1';
        \$this->f2();
    }
    function f2(){
        echo 'f2';
    }
}

\$x=new evalTest();
\$x->f2();
\$x->f1();";


eval($code);
echo 'test';
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/TCNh7tGI)

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes or protect \$, also you had error where you called f2(), use $this->f2
http://codepad.org/DkQ3PiTQ

```
$code='class evalTest{
    function f1(){
        echo "f1";
        $this->f2();
    }
    function f2(){
        echo "f2";
    }
}

$x=new evalTest();
$x->f2();
$x->f1();;';

eval($code);
echo 'test';
```

Comment: the single quotes -> double quotes does not matter. It's performing correctly as is (except for the $this->f2();)

Comment: he have `$x=new evalTest();` with double qoute it will expand as `=new evalTest();` check 1st then tell

Comment: Sigh...I figured I was just being stupid.  Thanks, I was definitely  missing the $this.

Comment: @PastorBones [**then why this doesn't work?**](http://codepad.org/bTGSVd5b) (because `$this` will be evaluated in double-quote string)